# UK Standard Visitor Visa for Indonesian citizen

Tags: visas, uk, standard-visitor-visas, proof-provenance-of-funds, indonesian-citizens

I am a Spanish citizen currently living in London, UK. I  have an Indonesian boyfriend and we are in a long distance relationship, I usually go to visit him (I have been going for almost 2 years). Now we would like to apply for a visitor visa for him to come to UK and visit his sister who is a citizen, but she is on benefits so she can not sponsor him financially. We would then go to Spain to visit my family.

We have looked at the application process and there are couple of circumstances which are making things more complicated. I can support him during his stay but I am not a UK citizen so I cannot sponsor him. His sister or some other friends can sponsor him but not support him financially. He has no permanent job in Indonesia as he is a painter and a driver so he cannot provide any letter from employer.

I was foolish because I thought we might need the flight to demonstrate that he will leave the country, and I already bought a ticket. Also, he heard that asking for multiply entry is impossible if it is the first time he wants to come to the UK. The plan was for him to come to the UK, we then go visit my family for 3 weeks in Spain, and return to the UK to take the return flight to Indonesia.

So many questions and nobody to answer them so I am struggling trying to find help.

Comment: From what you are writing the chances are very very very slim he will be approved for the visa. And when I checked, Slim has already headed out of town.

Comment: I've checked with the Citizen Advice here in Uk and they said, me as a person who legally lives in UK I can sponsor him, so maybe the chances are not too slim. Why do you think they are slim?

Comment: Clearly you are a novice at applying for visas because you would not ask that question if you had any experience. I would put the probability of approval at 5% or less.. Read smilar questions on the website and learn. No permanent job, needs a sponsor, from poor country, British girlfriend. Actually the probability of approval is closer to zero.

Comment: Obviusly I had no experience, I had a friend who had to leave Uk with a super good job just because he was arab and he was allowed to be here only 5 years, even he had money and everything. That is my only experience. Rest is me as a western travelling and not finding any problems which is mad if you think about it. Also I am not even British I am spanish which probably is even worse.

Answer (score 3):

You do not need to be a UK citizen to sponsor a visit https://assets.publishing.service.gov.uk/government/uploads/system/uploads/attachment_data/file/673351/Visit-guidance-v7.0EXT.PDF#page20 You do however have to demonstrate why you would sponsor him (eg proof of your relationship) and that you can afford to do so. UK visit visas are typically granted for 6 months, so the UK - Spain - UK - Indonesia itinerary you describe is possible. However the biggest stumbling block will be his personal circumstances in Indonesia - having a sponsor doesn’t absolve him from needing to qualify for a visit visa in his own right, typically this includes demonstrating intent to leave the UK at the end of the visit through strong economic and social ties to the applicant’s home country. You may find it helpful to read this answer [UK visa refusal on V 4.2 a + c (and sometimes 'e')](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/92121/uk-visa-refusal-on-v-4-2-a-c-and-sometimes-e)

Comment: In this case maybe is useful to show he has a kid in Australia and also he has few stamps in his passport that he was going there and coming back to Indonesia. Also maybe the flight could be something to demostrate he has at least a flight return ticket. For the relationship is more easy because for 2 years I was going there and also I can show few other proofs as maybe letters from friends or pictures. or a record of callings.

Comment: @Alixe Loba A child in Australia is unlikely to be seen as a reason to return to Indonesia. His travel history to Australia may help. Strong social/economic ties typically include one or more of a job, savings, property, dependents in the applicant’s country of residence. UKVI Visit visa rules specifically state that flights should not be booked before a visa is granted, therefore the ECO may discount his return flight at this point (although it will of course be relevant if/when arrives at a U.K. port of entry).

Comment: Yes, you are right I realized after a research about not getting the flights in advance, but because getting a visa for indonesia is just the opposite we thougth might help, but looks like is better if we don't even mention it. On the other hand Indonesia doeesn't work like uk so sometimes getting documents for activities like jobs or whatever is not tha easy because not everything is reglulated like in UK. The problem is how to prove he is coming back. We can get a letter from the landord as he got a new place for one year and there they pay in advance.

Comment: so maybe the letter and the bankstatement could work as there is no legal contract like in here. and try to gather other documents for proving he work as a painter there but like I said is more self employed and not a regulated activity so maybe will be worth it to get some extra advice from someone in Indonesia.

Comment: Is quite struggling and challenging at this point as we as western we don't have too many problems to access there but they even having sponsor like me now who can prove I have enough funds to support him is not easy. Also finding help to solve simple questions is insane I just spend 15 pounds just calling to the helpline (not free) in the inmigrations to ask the same and they even gave me a less human and not that good answer with information as you are giving me. So thanks for that by the way.

Comment: @Alixe Lobo Try not to over complicate the process. Read the official guidance carefully, including the guidance on supporting documents. Tick off what is available and identify what’s missing. For his job, if he’s self-employed bank statements and preferably tax returns should suffice. If you can’t gather enough evidence right now it may be best to work on addressing the evidential deficiencies before applying. I have successfully sponsored 2 visitor visas for my own partner, who is from a similarly disadvantaged country, but he at least could prove employment and dependent family.

Comment: @Alixe Lobo Also, start drafting the application online so you understand it. You can save it in draft and print it off to revise it as much as you need to. You’ll also need to draft your invitation letter to him, and a covering letter to the ECO https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/71874/what-details-should-a-good-cover-letter-contain-to-backup-a-uk-visit-visa-applic

Comment: Thanks for the advice I think we will focus now that we have 2 months and a half to try to address the problem of having enough proves he is coming back. Like he getting a job with a legal document or something like that. He already asked for the tax return because is a new law for getting out from the country now they need to ask for that document, but is something new. In my case he can not prove dependent family but we can have the house and try to get proof for the job. Also I will read carefully the link for the cover letter as we had the Australian one but is totally different.