# Rejection of UK Visitor Visa for V 4.2 (e) WITH Sponsor - pre-application advice requested

Tags: uk, standard-visitor-visas

I am a UK citizen living in Colombia and intend to return to home with my Colombian girlfriend for a month over Christmas to visit family.

My girlfriend is a student and from a modest Colombian background, hence she has basically no money in her bank account or an income.

I am going to act as her sponsor, covering the costs for the entire trip. However, I have heard that regardless of my sponsorship she may still be declined on the basis of her financial position. Is this true and are there any ways to address it?

In my letter I will specifically declare (with full honesty) that I will pay for ALL costs related to the trip.

I am happy to put money in her account *specifically declaring this in my sponsor letter and making clear that this money is at her disposal for emergencies during the trip* but worry that this could cause concerns of 'funds parking' regardless of my disclosure. **Has anyone done this before?**

For context, we are demonstrating economic ties through a letter from the university + proof of payment for the semester after we return to Colombia + other documents so my question is specifically related to failing on V 4.2 (e)

Comment: The answer to [this relevant question](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/92121/uk-visa-refusal-on-v-4-2-a-c-and-sometimes-e), especially the bit on sponsorship, may be relevant.

Comment: @B.Liu I seen that answer previously and don't feel it answers my question as it focuses on [4.2 a & c](https://www.gov.uk/guidance/immigration-rules/immigration-rules-appendix-v-visitor-rules). I am specifically asking about V 4.2 (e). What I hope to understand is that, assuming that my girlfriend qualifies on V4.2 a - d, is the need to have enough money to pay for the trip negated when a sponsor says they will 1. pay for everything, 2. can prove they have they funds to do so and 3. can prove they have a genuine relationship.

Comment: I think the section "Sponsorship Issues" in that answer might address your question, but perhaps not the way you want. Essentially, it said that money (section (e)) itself isn't usually a concern, but the applicant's ability to meet other rules in their own right. While your arrangement might not run afoul of V4.2e *assuming* one qualifies for V4.2 a-d, visa applications is considered as a whole (instead of a checkbox exercise, and often involve the term "a balance of probabilities"), and the premise that a applicant qualified on V4.2 a-d is perhaps a dangerous one.

Comment: @blackhaj From personal experience (my partner is Cuban), I have done this two ways successfully. The 1st time I sent him £1,500; we quoted this as his savings in the application. I stated I’d given him the money in expectation of the trip in my covering letter https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/71874/what-details-should-a-good-cover-letter-contain-to-backup-a-uk-visit-visa-applic and provided evidence to prove the transaction. The 2nd time we stated that he had no savings and I was paying for everything. IMHO the 2nd approach is more transparent.

Answer (score 3):

To avoid [concerns of funds parking](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/92121/uk-visa-refusal-on-v-4-2-a-c-and-sometimes-e), your best bet is most likely to:

1. Declare that you are supporting 100% of the expenses
2. Do not wire any money into her bank account
3. Show the statements of your accounts as proof of funds

This way you will not have to explain the sudden appearance of money ofunknown provenance into an account which is usually empty and/or does not regularly move.

Make sure that your accounts [demonstrate that you lead a stable life](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/66104/should-i-submit-bank-statements-when-applying-for-a-uk-visa-what-do-they-say-ab) and ensure that all the evidence you provide strengthens your case. In addition, see [this question for advice on how to write a quality cover letter](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/71874/what-details-should-a-good-cover-letter-contain-to-back-up-a-uk-visit-visa-appli).