# Will my application be affected if the person financing my trip was recently refused a visa?

Tags: uk, visa-refusals, proof-provenance-of-funds

My father is fully supporting me financially for my UK visit and sufficient documents regarding his finances are being included in my application.

However, when he applied for a visa for himself a couple of months ago, he provided bank statements and cover letter but didn't show the sources of the income or an invitation letter or anything else. As a result, he received a refusal.

Should I state in my cover letter or should he state in his letter of support that he was previously refused and explain the reasons for his refusal??

Comment: I’m confused. Did your father apply for a visa for himself and his visa was refused? Or did you apply for a visa using his financial documents and your visa was refused? There’s a big difference.

Comment: @RoboKaren I'm applying at the moment, my father is fully sponsoring me financially and all the papers that proves his financial situation are available and will be attached with my application. However, in July my father applied and he didn't provide anything except for Bank statements and Cover letter. He didn't provide sources of his income that support the amount of money in his Bank Statement or any other paper. As a result, in July, he was refused. Now my question is, should he state in the Letter of Support to My Application that he was refused in July and explain why?

Answer (score 2):

For a UK Visitor visa the applicant must provide details of any previous refusals when completing the application form. UKVI will have a record of the refusal and the reason(s). It’s not therefore necessary to duplicate this by explaining again in a cover or invitation letter.

Edit following OP clarification: despite having a sponsor the onus always remains on the applicant to prove that they qualify for a visa in their own right. See [UK visa refusal on V 4.2 a + c (and sometimes 'e')](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/92121/uk-visa-refusal-on-v-4-2-a-c-and-sometimes-e) IMHO therefore, although it’s not essential, providing a brief explanation of your father’s visa refusal in the context of his sponsorship won’t do any harm. This answer regarding the suggested format of a cover letter may help you [What details should a good cover letter contain to backup a UK Visit Visa application?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/71874/what-details-should-a-good-cover-letter-contain-to-backup-a-uk-visit-visa-applic)