# Australian Tourist Visa from Pakistan

Tags: visas, australia, tourist-visas, pakistani-citizens

I am applying as a tourist from Pakistan for Australia; I have one week vacation but  my wife does not like to travel with infants. I wanted to visit Sydney for tourism in these holidays.

What should I write in my cover letter to cover why I am travelling alone and what documents should I attach to make my application easy to process?

I am already attaching the following documents:

- previous UK VISA copy
- NOC from Employer
- Bank account statements and certificates
- Polio Certificate
- Tax Records
- Family Registration Certificate
- Kids Birth Certificates
- Wife Bank Account Statement
- Property Documents

Comment: Is a cover letter mandatory? It’s hard to see what you could write apart from the explanation you’ve given in your question.

Comment: Covering Letter explains your travel plan which is mandatory for Subclass 600, I just wanted to make sure that I am giving no reason for visa officer to deny my application. As I have 2 successful UK Visa and One Rejection of US B1/B2 visa so I don't want any more rejections on my profile. I am genuine traveler and had no reason of abandoning my country. I just looking for the most easiest way to explain this to the visa officer :)

Comment: Different target country but possible duplicate of [What details should a good cover letter contain to backup a UK Visit Visa application?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/71874/what-details-should-a-good-cover-letter-contain-to-backup-a-uk-visit-visa-applic)