# Is there anything we could add or change to this cover letter for a UK Standard Visitor Visa?

Tags: uk, us-citizens, standard-visitor-visas, applications

Please see [Standard Visitor Visa for US Citizen](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/131750/standard-visitor-visa-for-us-citizen) (I've forgotten my details!)

TL;DR U.S Girlfriend refused entry to UK in Nov 2018 due to belief she'd overstay her 6 months in the UK but have made big changes in circumstances since.

She has a biometrics appointment on April 22 for a new visa application. We wrote a cover letter (below) but we'd like to see if there's anything we could change or remove, or if there are any points that are irrelevant?

-

XXX, DOB: XX/XX/XXX, American national, GWF 00000000

To the Entry Clearance Officer,

I am seeking to visit the UK for a total of three weeks (XXXX - XXXX) in order to visit my boyfriend who lives in XXX, England. I was refused entry to the UK in November 2018 and my case number is #0000.

Since December 10 2018, I have been employed at XXXX as a part-time teacher and a part-time administrator with an average monthly wage of $XX for my part-time teaching role and a monthly wage of $XX for my administrative role. This administrative role has fixed hours of two days a week, 4 hours each day. My monthly wage  from my teaching role varies depending on how many hours I am needed for, and so I have calculated an average. I have also included bank statements outlining my finances, a letter of invitation from my boyfriend and a letter of approved vacation time from my employer in the United States.

My primary purpose of travel is to visit my boyfriend after he visited me here in the United States from December 26 2018 - January 23 2019 in order to maintain our long-distance relationship. XXX (boyfriend) and I met during his time working in the United States in July 2017 and have been in a long-distance relationship since. We communicate via video calls each day and regularly text each day in order to maintain our relationship.

He plans to visit me again in the near future, if after I am able to visit him in the UK, and if granted leave of absence from his employer.

During my time in the UK I will not be paying any costs towards accommodation as I will be staying with my boyfriend and his parents and my estimated cost for the total trip, including flights, is approximately 1400 USD. XXX and I will be staying in XXX throughout the duration of my visit.

After my visit I shall be returning to the United States to continue working as I am saving up for an apartment in XXXX. I am currently residing with my two parents.

Thank you for taking the time to consider my application.

Kind regards,

XXXXX

-

I've used 'XXX' in place of removed information (names, dates, locations).

After she was refused I visited her in the USA for one month. Would they be aware of this, and would it influence their decision in her visa?

Somebody mentioned in my last question on my other account, that I should include how we met and how often we communicate etc in my cover letter. Is this really advisable and would it be worthwhile? We have plenty of pictures together and we communicate every single day without failure but I don't quite think it would be all that necessary to include documentation of this as I don't believe the integrity of our relationship is even being questioned by Home Office officials.

Thanks. I hope the cover letter doesn't come across as desperate to the ECO but I feel as if it outlines our situation. Cheers!

Comment: FWIW, the letter looks ok to me. You’ve said ‘thank you’ twice (I’d delete the one at the start); yes, I would mention your visit to your gf after her denial of entry (they will be aware of it). Proving a genuine relationship isn’t necessary for a SVV so you don’t need to include documentation of when and where you met - mentioning it and explaining how often you communicate just helps set the scene for the ECO.

Comment: I've removed the thank you from the beginning and I've made slight changes to paragraphs 3 and 4.

Comment: She has applied for her SVV today and we are waiting for a decision. She has included a letter from her employer detailing approved vacation time, dates of intended travel (visit UK for 3wks), an invitation letter from myself, bank statements proving her finances and I have included in my invitation letter that I am due to start work mid-May 2019 shortly after she arrives along with my own passport number if they would like to look at me. Fingers crossed.

Comment: Update: She got her visa today which was approved.

Comment: @LR837 are you able to answer your own qusetion then, now that it's been approved?