# Will my girlfriend's estimated cost of trip, which is no longer accurate, affect her SVV application to the UK?

Tags: visas, uk, standard-visitor-visas

My girlfriend has applied for a SVV to the UK and stated the total estimated cost of her trip would be 1400 USD (about 1,082 GBP) for a three-week stay. This is because flights about a week ago were $800.

Upon checking flights today, after her application has been sent away, they were no cheaper than $1300 for a return.

The estimated cost of her trip is no longer accurate and I am concerned that they may think we are attempting to deceive them. She has approximately 6000 USD in her savings and checkings so can still comfortably cover the cost of any changes in flights. She has included proof of her finances in the form of bank statements with regular income from her job dating back the past 5 months.

Is there a way to rectify this incident after the application has already been sent out? Do you think they will be aware that the estimated cost of her trip is no longer accurate and find grounds for refusal?

Edit: Here are two posts I made explaining our situation, if needed. [Standard Visitor Visa for US Citizen](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/131750/standard-visitor-visa-for-us-citizen)

[Is there anything we could add or change to this cover letter for a UK Standard Visitor Visa?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/135813/is-there-anything-we-could-add-or-change-to-this-cover-letter-for-a-uk-standard?noredirect=1#comment337234_135813)

Comment: I suspect you’re over-thinking this. Your girlfriend can’t be expected to have a crystal ball regarding future flight costs - if the estimate was reasonable when the application was made and her documents show she can comfortably afford the increase (assuming they even check), I don’t think you should worry. There’s nothing you can do after submission anyway. If it helps, here are the full grounds for refusal https://assets.publishing.service.gov.uk/government/uploads/system/uploads/attachment_data/file/673999/GGFR-Section-2-v29.0EXT.PDF

Comment: Constantly experiencing post-application anxiety, ha. Not received any word as of today. Looks as if I'm going to visit her May 7-16 if she doesn't receive a reply before May 3.

Comment: Update: still no reply on her visa as they said it's been sent over to London for a decision there. I visited her for 9 days in the States.

Comment: Update: She obtained her visa today.

Comment: @LR837 can you add an answer for future users?

Answer (score 3):

Her visa was obtained on May 24. We submitted an invitation letter to the UK from me, payslips for about 5-6 months from her job, planned travel dates to the UK and a date she plans to return, and a cover letter from her (see here: [Is there anything we could add or change to this cover letter for a UK Standard Visitor Visa?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/135813/is-there-anything-we-could-add-or-change-to-this-cover-letter-for-a-uk-standard?noredirect=1#comment337234_135813)). The fact the estimated cost of trip increased after we sent the application didn't seem to affect it from what we could see but it's definitely possible the ECO was aware of this and took it into consideration.

There were no issues during the application process other than it went sent from New York, USA to Croydon, UK for administrative purposes. I think it took about 6-7 weeks to get a reply from her visa application.

She didn't travel to the UK until August 2 and she stayed until August 21 before returning to USA. On her entry to the UK she was sat aside for 15 minutes while the IO asked her to wait. He then went off alone and came back 15 minutes later before allowing her entry on her visa.