# UK visitor's visa refused for my dad who is retired

Tags: uk, visa-refusals, proof-of-accommodation

Can you provide me some explanation why my father's UK general visa was refused?

He is retired, receives pension and he did provide his bank statement, he also provided documents that prove he owns a property in his home country.

I want to cover all his expenses, that is why I provided my bank statement. I'm not sure if the amount was not sufficient? He also stated on his application that I'm going to provide him with accommodation. Unfortunately, I didn't provide proof that I own a house in London. Would this fix the issue, if he reapplies? Shall I provide land registry documents or my  mortgage documents?

What seems strange is they are asking why my father hasn't visited me for 4 years. I don't think it's their business, to be honest! We were just settling in with my wife, now finally we have our own property, we also had a son and now he is 2 years old and it is more manageable to have visitors and leave him with his granddad occasionally. My wife is a stay at home mum and during my dad's visit she was planning to look for jobs, go[image] for interviews as my dad would be extra help with childcare. Shall I explain these reasons?

What other paperwork should my father provide? Should I write a cover letter explaining all the circumstances about providing accommodation and funds and why we he didn't come to visit us for the past 4 years since we are in UK ?

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Yes, IMHO you should have explained the background to the application. It is typical to include an invitation and a covering letter with the application, did you do this? https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/71874/what-details-should-a-good-cover-letter-contain-to-back-up-a-uk-visit-visa-appli Which section(s) of the Immigration rules were quoted as the reasons for refusal? It may help to read this https://assets.publishing.service.gov.uk/government/uploads/system/uploads/attachment_data/file/673351/Visit-guidance-v7.0EXT.PDF if you’ve not done so already

Comment: V 4.2 to 4.10 apendix V

Comment: What is your father’s citizenship? You are an EEA national? What type of visa did your father apply for? https://www.gov.uk/family-permit

Comment: I seem to remember seeing earlier questions where a grandparent or a young relative was refused a visa or entry because they mentioned babysitting. Don't have time to look now.

Comment: he applied for general visitor visa. i am spouse of EEA national.

Comment: Do not say a word about your dad helping you with childcare. This is considered illegal work in the UK.

Comment: It seems your father submitted evidence that _you can afford_ to sponsor his state, but didn't actually submit any evidence that _you have any intention_ to sponsor him. Which may be obvious to you that you would pay for his stay, but not for the government.

Comment: "I don't think it's their business, to be honest!" - If your father wants to visit the UK, then it is.

Answer (score 3):

> **my dad would be extra help with childcare**.

You need to be careful when using nonresident family members instead of employing UK residents for childcare

> Where a family member is coming to look after a child in the UK, this is permitted provided it is for a short visit and does not amount to the relative being employed as a child-minder. You must be satisfied that the visit is of a short duration, the relative is a genuine visitor and will not live in the UK for extended periods through frequent or successive visits.

UK Home-Office "Visit Guidance" version 9.0

---

> **Can you provide me some explanation why my father's UK general visa was refused?**

The letter you received gives some explanation

> It is unclear to me why you have not visited your son to date

In your application, provide the reasons

> the documents you have provided do not show that your son is willing and able to fund your visit and provide accomodation.

I suspect you need to provide a letter stating that you are willing

You also need to show that you can afford to support your father for the period. I believe that would ideally be bank statements showing regular income and gradually accumulating savings well in excess of any expected expenditure on your father, including provision for unplanned expenses (maybe non-urgent medical etc).

Answer (score 2):

You appear to have failed to provide sufficient documentation to support the statements made in the application. For example:

- a letter of invitation (addressed to your father) stating the reason for the invitation, dates of the proposed visit, the address where your father will stay, how you will cover his costs, how travel arrangements will be made once the visa is approved etc
- a covering letter (addressed to the ECO) explaining the premise of the visit, your employment and salary, details of the accommodation where your father will stay, and other relevant information to help convince the ECO that a genuine personal relationship exists (this is why the fact that there have been no previous visits is relevant - very much the ECO’s business, despite what your opinion is) eg how often and how you maintain contact [What details should a good cover letter contain to back up a UK Visit Visa application?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/71874/what-details-should-a-good-cover-letter-contain-to-back-up-a-uk-visit-visa-appli)
- your employment contract and 6 months’ bank statements (since you are covering costs) [Should I submit bank statements when applying for a UK Visa? What do they say about me?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/66104/should-i-submit-bank-statements-when-applying-for-a-uk-visa-what-do-they-say-ab)

IMHO you do not need to provide your land registry or mortgage documents [Visiting the UK: guide to supporting documents](https://www.gov.uk/government/publications/visitor-visa-guide-to-supporting-documents/guide-to-supporting-documents-visiting-the-uk)

Comment: thanks a lot for the detailed info. so what's the difference between cover letter and invitation letter? can put all in one? can it be a scanned copy or I shall send it via post to my father?

Comment: @user94220 The invitation is addressed to your father. The cover letter is addressed to the ECO; its overall purpose is to explain the background to the invitation. Documents should be originals so probably best to type them, sign by hand and post if you can. I’m not sure if a scanned copy would be accepted. Also to note that your father will have to declare the refusal in all subsequent UK visa applications (apologies if you’re already aware of that). Ideally he should also demonstrate strong ties to his home country eg dependent family there, as a compelling reason to return home.

Answer (score 2):

You need to make sure that you give sufficient proof that your father is just coming to UK on a holiday and as a tourist. Never mention that he is going to take care of his grandson or help you or your wife with your personal issues, this would make them believe that your father would stay here permanently. Ask your father to consult a Chartered accountant and get a proof of income (even if he is a pensioner) or tax/IT documents and submit those along with the VISA application. 
If your dad has any property, submit the copy of those documents as well. In the comments section make sure you write that he is just visiting UK for tourism and he has a family back in India that is dependant on him and he will be going back. 
Once you get your VISA, it is mandatory that he has a return ticket in his hand when he goes for immigration in UK. They will ask for it and even send them back if they dont have a valid return ticket.