# Previous visa refusal query - UK

Tags: visas, uk, visa-refusals

I'm planning to apply for UK visa but in October last year my schengen visa from Greece was rejected stating:

```
1- Justification for the purpose and conditions of intended stay was not provided.
2- The information submitted regarding the justification for the purpose and 
conditions of intended stay was not reliable.
```

Basically I feel the issue with my Greece application was that I did not provide a cover letter explaining the purpose of the visit.

A brief background about myself: I'm single and have been working for a bank for last 4 years. Living with my family in UAE for last 8 years. I hardly travel but last year was awarded a travel voucher by my employer and now this trip is to redeem the same.

So kindly advise how should i address the the below question in UK visa application.

"Have you ever been refused a visa to any another country other than UK and kindly explain what happened."

Answer (score 4):

You answer ‘Yes’ and state the Schengen country that refused you and the two reasons given for the refusal. You can add to this if you wish by explaining the contributing factors as you see them, either in the ‘other information’ section at the end of the application or in a covering letter if you’re providing one (it’s not mandatory [What details should a good cover letter contain to back up a UK Visit Visa application?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/71874/what-details-should-a-good-cover-letter-contain-to-back-up-a-uk-visit-visa-appli))

I think your interpretation of the basis on which your Schengen visa application was refused is too simplistic. It may help if you read these before applying [Schengen Visa Refusal: Justification for the purpose and conditions of the intended stay was not provided](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/52782/schengen-visa-refusal-justification-for-the-purpose-and-conditions-of-the-inten) and [Schengen Visa Refusal: Justification for the purpose and conditions of the intended stay was not reliable](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/53411/schengen-visa-refusal-justification-for-the-purpose-and-conditions-of-the-inten)