# Documents for UK visa

Tags: paperwork, standard-visitor-visas, applications, family, vacations

I’m intending to apply for a U.K. Standard Visitor visa for me and my wife . My wife works for a multi national company and I run my private business. This is our third years of marriage and we do not have a child yet. So we decided to take a 2 weeks vacation to the U.K. . I have some concerns because, my wife’s passport does not carry my name because she had the passport before we got married and she has only traveled to South Africa ones .

- Please, kindly make a A-Z list of the documents we should put together for the visa application
- what should our introduction letter to the embassy look like ?
- Is it advisable to include our marriage pictures?
  Thank you.

Comment: What is your nationality?

Comment: This is pretty close to being too broad to answer.

Comment: 'Kindly make a list...' No. The documents you need will be listed on the web site when you start your application.

Answer (score 1):

The UK does not care whether you have the same last name or not. Plenty of married couples do not have the same last name.

If your wife did legally change her name on marriage but did not change her passport then it might be advisable to include your marriage certificate or another document recording the name change.

If you include a marriage certificate then wedding photos will probably not help.

You should include whatever other documents the application instructions ask for in your circumstances.

Answer (score 0):

This https://assets.publishing.service.gov.uk/government/uploads/system/uploads/attachment_data/file/793361/Visit-guidance-v8.0ext.pdf tells you pretty much everything you need to know. A cover letter isn’t mandatory; most of what goes in it is typically included in the application itself so it just duplicates and gives the ECO yet another paper to read. However, there’s some guidance here [What details should a good cover letter contain to back up a UK Visit Visa application?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/71874/what-details-should-a-good-cover-letter-contain-to-back-up-a-uk-visit-visa-appli)