# UK Family Visitor Visa Refused, Need advice if to reapply

Tags: uk, visa-refusals, standard-visitor-visas

We have recently applied for a UK family visit visa for our uncle who is 65 years old. Visa applied in New Delhi and refused. 
We are baffled by the statement that ECA/ECO have received the bank statement and could read the account number but could not find the balance on it. I could understand if they stated the quality of the scan was poor therefore they could not read the statement. On point 2, we also briefly explained on the covering letter from my Uncle that he uses contractor for labour and machniery for day to day work. He is only responsible for crop sale, tax, purchase of seeds and fertiliser and that is not to happen until the end of Oct after his return to India as the current crop is already planted.

I know this is a not a legal advice forum, but based on your experience, is there any point reapplying with the same refreshed bank statement with a letter from the branch manager stating the balance and further clarifications on management of his farm in his absence and supporting letter from the contractor or it is not worth as they made assumptions to Annex V a) & c) of the rules.

[image]

****Answer to traveiler's comment moved here to avoid confusion********

@ Traveller. All financial details (income tax and bank statements) were uploaded by me as one PDF file. The front page of the bank statement has 3 places where the balance is stated. Closing Balance, Effective Available balance and itemized transaction balance.

On point 2, I did not state this point specifically in the additional information but stated in a cover letter written from my uncle side. Text is below. We did not supply any further evidences to emphasise on this point as our application was assumed straight forward and I never had any issue in past with Home Office for my parents or in laws, last application experience in 2013 with probably half the details.

*I am a farmer and work on my ancestral agriculture land including my siblings share. I am slowly moving towards retirement, where I arrange all my labour, machinery etc. on contract. I manage crop sales, legal, land issues etc. My planned travel is between Aug to Oct is on the basis: I want to utilise the time before the planted paddy (rice) crop is ready for sale. This time also coincides with summer school holidays in England and late summer/early autumn warm, dry and stable weather*

*****UPDATE 09/08/2019 ***********

Please can someone help by answering the question whether to reapply by addressing the missing information ourselves? or does this needs to be done via a solicitor, they are expensive; costs are not justified for an ordinary family visitor visa if that is the expectation from UKVI.

Comment: Did you submit original statements? Is it possible that part of the statements were obscured or cut off in the scan so that eg it showed transactions but the resulting balance(s) was not visible? Did you include the information about your uncle’s farm responsibilities in the ‘additional information’ at the end of the application itself?

Comment: It sounds like there might be some technical problems on top, but as §V4.2 is mentioned in the last sentence, it might be relevant to read: https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/92121/uk-visa-refusal-on-v-4-2-a-c-and-sometimes-e

Comment: @Contributor NB I don’t necessarily interpret the text starting ‘I am slowly moving towards retirement’ as ‘I won’t be needed on the farm during my absence because I employ a contract labourer and only concern myself with crop sales etc that are already organised and won’t need my further attention until my return’.

Comment: @ContributorNB you should [contact SE support](https://travel.stackexchange.com/contact) to get them to merge your accounts.  That will enable you to edit your question in future, and more importantly, to accept an answer if a good one comes along.

Comment: @ Madhatler, I did contact them as suggested. thank you.

Comment: @Travelier to your last comment yes I understand the cover letter was a little bit weaker but intention was genuine. No one answered the question if any point to reapply immediately with clarifications and this time give the bank statement and other original documentation to VFS staff for scanning.

Answer (score 1):

If you are certain that you can satisfy all the refusal reasons from the first application, then yes, IMHO re-applying is worth it although there’s no guarantee of success and you will of course need to declare the refusal in any subsequent application.

If you’ve not done so already, it might help to read this [What details should a good cover letter contain to back up a UK Visit Visa application?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/71874/what-details-should-a-good-cover-letter-contain-to-back-up-a-uk-visit-visa-appli) and [UK visa refusal on V 4.2 a + c (and sometimes 'e')](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/92121/uk-visa-refusal-on-v-4-2-a-c-and-sometimes-e)

Comment: Thanks. No one can be certain as visa is privilege. Legal advice taken on the issue advises re-application. A complaint has a 50-50 chance but may not generate any response which defeats the object of travel at a set time. As I said earlier, I never had an issue previously may be at that time appeals were allowed. I always found UK home office reasonable. May be hostile environment or a revenue generation tactic to find errors.   I always believed ordinary application with modest documentation pictures reality not 6 months advance preparation with legal advice which is more open to fraud.