# From India to UK on Tier 2 ICT Long Term Visa & wants my wife to join me on Standard Visitor Visa

Tags: visas, uk, india

I am from India and traveling to the UK next week with Tier-2 ICT Long Term visa for the period of three months & I want my wife (also from India) to join me in the UK & stay with me in a rented apartment.

Here are my queries related to my wife's travel.

1. Can my wife come to the UK on a Standard Visitor Visa and stay with me?
2. When can she apply for Visa? before I travel to the UK or after I
   reach the UK or only after I get my BRP/Residence Permit Card?
3. Is a cover letter and sponsorship letter mandatory as I will be her
   sponsor? Also, can I request to share sample Cover/sponsorship letters.
4. She will be taking 2 months leave from her company to come to the UK
   & if needed she may work from the UK remotely to support her work. Do I
   need to mention this in cover letter?
5. Do I need to take NOC from landlord for my wife's stay?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Q1 Your wife is eligible to apply for a Visitor visa in the usual way up to 3 months before the planned travel date. https://www.gov.uk/standard-visitor-visa

Q2 IMHO since you already have your visa she has the option to apply now or wait until you are actually in the UK. Since you’ll be travelling pretty soon, it might be better to wait.

Q3 A letter from you supporting her application is essential, without this she has no demonstrable premise for the visit. There is no standard format. This question should help you compile one [What details should a good cover letter contain to back up a UK Visit Visa application?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/71874/what-details-should-a-good-cover-letter-contain-to-back-up-a-uk-visit-visa-appli)

Q4 Your wife needs to be very careful to present herself as a genuine visitor (see V4.2 of the Immigration Rules https://www.gov.uk/guidance/immigration-rules/immigration-rules-appendix-v-visitor-rules). Showing that she can continue working while visiting the UK for a reasonably extended period undermines somewhat the case that her job is a tie to home / compelling reason to return and therefore an ECO might view it as an indicator of an intention to overstay. Note however, that working remotely while visiting is not against the Rules in itself [Where can I travel for prolonged periods of time while legally working remotely for a company in my home country?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/45092/where-can-i-travel-for-prolonged-periods-of-time-while-legally-working-remotely/45492#45492)

Q5 Yes, you should provide your landlord’s approval along with other relevant supporting documents such as your wife’s bank statements, employment contract etc https://www.gov.uk/government/publications/visitor-visa-guide-to-supporting-documents/guide-to-supporting-documents-visiting-the-uk