# How to apply for a UK visa when the person isn't living in their home country

Tags: visas, uk, standard-visitor-visas, egyptian-citizens, proof-of-ties

I've been looking into visas and I've seen so much information about denials it's freaked me out a little. My boyfriend is Egyptian and is currently studying in Oman, where his mother and father are also living (not nationals either, work related).

We're hoping he can come visit me in January as I visited him in March, but I'm so worried his visa will be denied. He doesn't have a job, his living expenses are paid for by his father, as would the UK trip. I'm concerned that all of this info would be red flags to the officers (that he's from egypt, doesn't have a job, isn't residing in his home country, is visiting his girlfriend).

The ties that I can think of are school and that his family live there but would that be enough/how would we put this in the application, for example, should we get a letter or any form of documentation from his uni, such as stating his enrollment, maybe that he's taking time off (he may be taking the first week of term off)?

Comment: It’s not impossible for him to get a visa. He should plan to visit in the school holidays rather than taking time out of term, and keep the visit relatively short. Reading https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/103826/how-to-prove-that-you-have-significant-ties-with-family-in-your-home-country and https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/71874/what-details-should-a-good-cover-letter-contain-to-back-up-a-uk-visit-visa-appli might help, also https://assets.publishing.service.gov.uk/government/uploads/system/uploads/attachment_data/file/827480/Visit-guidance-v9.0ext.pdf

Comment: We can’t know and thus we cannot give a good answer as to whether a specific visa application will be denied. We have a number of questions the answers to which outline what to avoid when going for a UK visa. Specifically, practically any answer by user [Gayot Fow](https://travel.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3A1737+is%3Aanswer) should provide assistance on what to avoid.

Comment: @Traveller thank you so much for the links! I'll check them out. He'll be visiting out of term time, but we figured we could extend the trip a week as the first week of uni is just intros. would 4 weeks be too long to an officer?

Comment: @wacomhelp Look at it from the ECO’s point of view - your boyfriend says being enrolled at university is a compelling reason for him to return to his home country. But he plans to miss a week at the start of term. Possible ECO conclusion: hmmm, not all that compelling after all, perhaps he won’t go back at all. If this is his first visit, I recommend that you play everything by the book - a refusal now will harm his future chances, whereas an approval does the opposite.

Comment: @Traveller great advice, thank you so much! It's a shame but it's definitely the safer option

Comment: Does he have a proper student visa in oman?

Comment: @PeterGreen hi peter! he doesn't, he's on his dad's work visa, i think it's called a companion visa? would a student visa affect the uk visa application?