# Writing a letter of Explanation Canada, Please Advise on Missing information

Tags: visas, canada, paperwork, nigerian-citizens

I am writing a letter of Explanation, Kindly advise if there appears to be something I am missing.

> (xxxxxxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxx) (My name)
>
> (xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx) My address
>
> 27th December,2019
>
> The visa officer,
>   Immigration, Refugees and Citizenship, Canada
>   70-9900 King George Blvd, 
>   Surrey, 
>   BC V3T 4Y3, 
>   Canada
>
> Dear Sir / Madam,
>
> Re : Letter of Explanation for temporary residence visa (XXXXXXX XXXX)
>
> I hope this letter clarifies my intentions as regards to the visit visa which was earlier rejected.
>
> My name is XXXXX XXXX, a Nigerian Citizen. I currently work as a Software engineer for XYZ Bank Plc full-time here in Nigeria and also
>   I have a remote job which I work part time for extra income. My salary
>   monthly (from my full-time job is about 450,000 before tax and 427,500
>   after tax monthly in Nigerian Nairas, and 5,130,000 nairas, after tax
>   annually) and my part-time job I make about 350,000 naira from my
>   remote job monthly where I work as a Mobile applications Developer.
>   Altogether I make 777,000 (Seven hundred and seventy seven thousand
>   Nigerian nairas) which is about 2,777.85 Canadian dollars monthly and
>   33,334.20 Canadian dollars annually. I also run my fathers Business, 
>   XXXXXXXXX Enterprises which I work as the Executive Managing director
>   from which I also raise Income as well, as well as income for the
>   family (since its a family business). I have attached my personal
>   second bank statement from GTBank (Which I use for business for your
>   viewing) and the Business Name registration Documents for your
>   viewing.
>
> I have attached the following documents for your viewing as requested from me :
>
> - Application for temporary Residence Visa
> - Business Registration Documents (Business Name Registration and Affidavits)
> - Datapage of My passport
> - Invitation Letter (From Inviting party)
> - Proof of means of Financial Support (Here I uploaded my 2 Bank Statements (i) Salary Account (ii) Business Accounts)
> - Purpose of Travel (Itinerary, Confirmed Hotel Reservations. Itinerary should show my arrival and departure details to and From
>     Canada )
>
> I also have landed properties of Real estate with address Plot XXX Works layout, in Owerri in which I have the Certificate of Occupancy
>   born in my fathers name and which my father has given to me to manage.
>   I have since attached the documentation as well as well as affidavits
>   affirming and confirming this issue. In which we receive rental money
>   from our tenants which is valued at about 3 million naira and the
>   property is valued at over 140 million naira.
>
> I will be visiting Alberta, Canada for about 13 days to see a family friend XXXXX who I have not seen for over 12 years. I have also attached an Itinerary and invitation letter from the invting party detailing my purpose of visit as well as hotel reservation upon arrival from Lagos to Calgary, Alberta. I will also be visiting My friend in Grand Prairie, Alberta after which I would return to Nigeria to concentrate on my office work again as well as other businesses I run here.
>
> All other documentation as requested has since been uploaded for your viewing. And should there be any concerns as well as information needed to make available, kindly let me know so I should present it immediately.
>
> Regards,
>   XXXXXXXXXX

Comment: ‘I write to use this Medium’??  What on earth does that mean? This might help https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/71874/what-details-should-a-good-cover-letter-contain-to-back-up-a-uk-visit-visa-appli

Comment: @Traveller, I am applying online and I would be using a letter of explanation for backup, thats what i mean "This medium" sir

Comment: It’s unnecessary verbiage. Imagine how many covering letters Visa Officers have to wade through.

Comment: @Traveller, Kindly look up again... I have deleted all you spoke of

Comment: @Traveller, Pls confirm if there are other things I need to add. as regards to this letter. I have done some Edits so far

Comment: @Traveller, kindly look and let me know other things I need to make present;

Comment: @Traveller, You there? you did not give an answer as regards to this. I asked as to know if there are anything I left out

Comment: You're not by any chance Robert https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/106617/robert are you? If so I believe you can get a mod to merge your accounts.

Answer (score 1):

Your point should be to address the issues raised in the previous rejection, and to give all the information they need which addresses their concerns.

Their concerns are that they think you will not leave Canada at the end of your planned stay. You must convince them otherwise by establishing strong ties to your home country (a permanent job with a decent revenue -- by Canadian standards, not Nigerian ones). You should on the other hand probably not drown them in a lot of unnecessary documents and verbiage.

Instead of giving lots of bits and pieces of information about everything and their cousin, make sure you have complete and exhaustive information **and supporting documents** on the points that actually count.

As it stands, the information you give looks quite confusing and can be perceived as bit contradictory. You state you have a full time job, plus a part time remote job, plus a job managing your family's business. This is clearly confusing.

Also, you are mixing business and personal accounts and revenue. This is a common mistake, but the officer handling your application does not care about the revenue of any company you own, manage, or work for. They care about **your** revenue.

For your full-time job, you should:

- Provide evidence of that job (your work contract, and at least your last 3 payslips).
- Provide at least your last 3 bank account statements.
- Make sure your salary correctly shows up on your bank account statements and the amounts match.

For your part-time job, what is your status? Are you self-employed? Running a company? Salaried? You should provide associated relevant information. Correctly separate any business income and statements from your own actual income and statements. In many cases, you should not even provide any business income or statements, though this may vary.

For your job managing your family's company, the same applies. Are you salaried of that company? If so, provide work contract, pay slips, and bank account statements which show those payments. If not, the income and statements of the company are probably not very relevant.

Prefer having (simple, concise) tabular information rather than long text. Which do you think is clearer? You long and convoluted explanation:

> My salary monthly (from my full-time job is about 450,000 before tax and 427,500 after tax monthly in Nigerian Nairas, and 5,130,000 nairas, after tax annually) and my part-time job I make about 350,000 naira from my remote job monthly where I work as a Mobile applications Developer. Altogether I make 777,000 (Seven hundred and seventy seven thousand Nigerian nairas) which is about 2,777.85 Canadian dollars monthly and 33,334.20 Canadian dollars annually.

(and that's only a small part of it)

Or:

```
Job                          | Monthly Salary (NGN) | Monthly Salary (CAD)
-----------------------------+----------------------+---------------------
Software Engineer @ XYZ Bank |          450 000 NGN |            ±1600 CAD
App Developer @ Foobar Co.   |          350 000 NGN |            ±1250 CAD
-----------------------------+----------------------+---------------------
Total                        |          800 000 NGN |            ±2850 CAD
```

(I have no idea why in one case you have figures before and after tax and in the other only one figure).

Your situation is complex enough that it probably warrants using the services of a **good, honest** lawyer (not some agency that will pretend to do the right thing and file bogus info). Remember that you remain solely responsible for anything that is filed in your name, so **do not** let anyone submit documents which do not represent the truth.

Comment: from what you say here, i think I would only showcase the part for office full-time job, since the other remote one is self employed  business and I get the funds in my personal business account and not salary account. I would take it out from the letter too. I would only show the part of the full-time job and the business since I gave the both as information (Even though i have documentation for all the jobs, both the remote and full-time)

Comment: thanks for the note. Now I only attached 2 bank statements, one is my salary account and the other is my personal account. the Salary account shows the places where my salary was received inside my bank account. As for the second bank which is just the normal business account I used for business, i put in a second merger and put in one pdf as well..

Comment: for the business , its actually my fathers business, having passed on to me, it becomes mine. So i got affidavits to back it up in this case. I have clarified that in the Letter of Explanation now.

Comment: As I wrote, your situation is complex. The issue with keeping only your full time salaried job is that the relevant revenue is not very high by Canadian standards. Also, there must be income on your bank statements coming from those other activities, which would then become unexplained, especially if they are not regular (it would then look like funds parking). Also, the cost of your trip should be compatible with the justified revenue and savings. I believe you need to include those sources of revenue, but must be a lot clearer on how those work **for you**.