# Refused Schengen visa with new passport

Tags: paperwork, schengen-visas, tourist-visas, applications, serial-refusals

I was refused a tourist Schengen visa at the Netherlands consulate in January 2019 as a businessman. My passport got stolen so, later on, I got a new passport and I applied for a business visa at France consulate in May 2019 which was also refused though I stated in my application that am employed and also a businessman. How do I write my cover letter for a tourist Schengen visa at Holland consulate in my next application?

Comment: Although it refers to a UK visa, this https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/71874/what-details-should-a-good-cover-letter-contain-to-back-up-a-uk-visit-visa-appli may help. But with two Schengen refusals already, even the best-written cover letter probably won’t make a difference unless your circumstances have changed sufficiently so that the refusal reason(s) no longer apply to you. You might get better answers if you tell us why your applications were refused.

Comment: All the talk about your passport is confusing. Is it in any way relevant for your question that your old passport was stolen and you got a new one? If not, could you please edit your question and remove all unnecessary details?

Comment: What was the reason given for your visa refusal?

Comment: @Michael the refusal reasons are: 1. You have not provided proof of sufficient means of subsistence for the duration of the intended stay. 2. Justification for the purpose and conditions of the intended stay was not provided. 3. Your intention to leave the territory of the member states before the expiry of the visa could not be ascertained. 4. The information regarding the justification for the purpose and conditions of the intended stay was not reliable.

Comment: Using a new passport will just get you another visa refusal. See [Justification for the purpose and conditions of the intended stay was not provided](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/52782/3221) to learn what you need to do to get the visa.