# Sponsorship for UK visa

Tags: uk, paperwork, standard-visitor-visas, applications, visa-sponsors

I am a Ghanaian studying in Ukraine and I am applying for visa to visit my uncle in the UK. My dad is sponsoring, so I provided his bank statement. Do I also need to provide my personal bank statement which has a lesser account balance(to prove that I am catered for in Ukraine)?
Is it okay if my uncle does not provide his bank statement?
Also, should I add a cover letter from my side?
Is £1000 too much or to small for a duration of 14 days in my uncle’s apartment?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Should I submit bank statements when applying for a UK Visa? What do they say about me?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/66104/should-i-submit-bank-statements-when-applying-for-a-uk-visa-what-do-they-say-ab) Also relevant https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/71874/what-details-should-a-good-cover-letter-contain-to-back-up-a-uk-visit-visa-appli

Comment: Under current Covid rules, a 14 day visit doesn’t make much sense. Ukraine is on the UK’s amber list, meaning if you are not fully vaccinated under the UK vaccination programme, you will have to quarantine on arrival and take both the day 2 and day 8 tests.

Comment: @Traveller even if OP is fully vaxxed, they can't escape isolation as it's only for British residents right?