# UK Priority Business Visa Refusal

Tags: uk, indian-citizens, visa-refusals, standard-visitor-visas

My application for Business Visa for 6 months got rejected under paragraph(s) V4.2 and V4.3 of Appendix V:

1. I had applied for permission to visit the UK for 30 days business trip. But they misread the amount that company will provide to me for my expenses and cost of my trip. A zero was missed by them.
2. I had recently joined my company, so I didn't had salary slip of my current company who was inviting me. I submitted my previous company's salary slip, and appointment letter of current employer. They have mentioned that they are unable to verify authenticity of my employment.
   I have given my bank statements for 3 months as well as Fixed Deposit details. I usually dont keep money in savings account and create FD every month for extra money that I have. Is it OK or its necessary to have money in savings.
   My company is again applying for UK Business Visa. What all documents should I attach this time? I am scared to submit application this time.
   Should I also provide a justification letter mentioning previous refusal's circumstances and corrections done now. Please let me know what all documents should I enclose this time.
   [image: Refusal Letter]

Comment: Joining a new company and immediately getting sent on a 30 day trip to the UK could be considered unusual. What type of employment is it and why os it necessary to visit the UK?  Is your new employer based in the UK? The refusal letter mentions you have no travel history in the last 10 years.  What ties to your country of residence apart from your job do you have?

Comment: What is an "FD" that you create every month for your excess money?

Comment: Is your new emoyer big? Small? Recently set up? Registered as a company?

Comment: You might learn something from reading https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/92121/uk-visa-refusal-on-v-4-2-a-c-and-sometimes-e

Comment: @DJClayworth I think FD = fixed deposit.

Answer (score 4):

> Please let me know what documents should I enclose this time

- Official letter(s) from your new employer printed on company headed paper, detailing your role, salary and length of employment, and stating the business reason for your visit including a credible reason why your *physical presence in the UK is essential*
- An itinerary for your stay in the UK and proof of any meetings or other business-related activities that you plan to undertake, for example, letters from inviting organisations, and so on, to evidence your attendance at any meetings or conferences, etc.
- Unless self-evident (for example a major plc, or a well-known employer in India etc), proof that your new employer has the financial resources to fulfil its sponsorship commitment
- Bank statements showing salary payments from your new employer. You should typically provide six months’ worth, even though in your case only the most recent statements will show salary payments from your new employer [Should I submit bank statements when applying for a UK Visa? What do they say about me?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/66104/should-i-submit-bank-statements-when-applying-for-a-uk-visa-what-do-they-say-ab) FD statements show you have savings but are not much help if the money is not readily accessible.
- Proof of ties to your country of residence, over and above your new employment.
- Include a covering letter that explains anything not obvious from the application itself [What details should a good cover letter contain to back up a UK Visit Visa application?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/71874/what-details-should-a-good-cover-letter-contain-to-back-up-a-uk-visit-visa-appli)

See also [UK visa refusal on V 4.2 a + c (and sometimes 'e')](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/92121/uk-visa-refusal-on-v-4-2-a-c-and-sometimes-e)